# Prove the inequality $(1+2^{x-1}+2^y)(1+2^{y-1}+2^z)(1+2^{z-1}+2^x)\leq 2^{x^2+y^2+z^2+3}$

Tags: inequality, exponentiation, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

*question*

Let $x,y,z$ natural nonzero numbers. Prove that:

> $(1+2^{x-1}+2^y)(1+2^{y-1}+2^z)(1+2^{z-1}+2^x)\leq 2^{x^2+y^2+z^2+3}$

*my idea*

I don't know why but the first thing I thought of was to break down the parentheses, but I don't think this is a really good idea.

I know this type of inequality is proved using the inequality of means or CBS. To be honest, this inequality reminds me of AM-GM.

The thing is I never know where to start from. Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

*edit*

Without loss of generality, I let $x\leq y\leq z$ (I don't think this is going to help us that much, but still)

by AM-GM

$\sqrt[\leftroot{10} \uproot{5} 3]{(1+2^{x-1}+2^y)(1+2^{y-1}+2^z)(1+2^{z-1}+2^x)} \leq \frac{3+2^{x-1}(1+2)+2^{y-1}(1+2)+2^{z-1}(1+2)}{3}$

$\sqrt[\leftroot{10} \uproot{5} 3]{(1+2^{x-1}+2^y)(1+2^{y-1}+2^z)(1+2^{z-1}+2^x)} \leq 1+2^{x-1}+2^{y-1}+2^{z-1}$

$(1+2^{x-1}+2^y)(1+2^{y-1}+2^z)(1+2^{z-1}+2^x) \leq  {(1+2^{x-1}+2^{y-1}+2^{z-1})}^3$

Comment: does natural nonzero numbers mean integers $\ge 1$? if so, maybe you can start with $(1 + 2^{x-1} + 2^y) \le 2^{x^2/3 + 2y^2/3 + 1}$.

Comment: Your first idea is good. Expand out the LHS, the largest term is $2^{x+y+z}$ which is smaller than $2^{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ because we're working with the positive integers (and gets much worse for large integers). The next largest term is like $2^{x+y+z-3}$, which is half that value. So, Show then that we can bound the LHS with $ 8 \times 2^{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

Comment: @Yimin Yes, you are right!

Comment: @CalvinLin the next largest is $2^{x+y+z-1}$?

Comment: @Yimin That's what I thought at first, but you actually can't get it so I made the edit (but didn't fix the "half that value" part). EG If you want $x-1$ from the first term, then you need to pick $y-1, z-1$ from the next terms. $\quad$ Also, have to watch out for terms like $ 2x+z - 1$, $2x+y  - 2$.

Comment: @CalvinLin, Ah, I get it, do you mean it should be first using $2^{x-1} + 1 \le 2^x$, then use your argument?

Comment: @Yimin tbh I've not worked through the details (esp since this question might be closed due to lack of context). I believe using things like $2^a + 2^b \leq 2^{\max(a, b) + 1}$ and $2x+z - 1 \leq x^2 + z $ will get us most of the way there.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thank you for your idea, but I don't understand your idea that well. So we break the parentheses and then try to show that is $\leq$ than RHS. But how can I show that>

Comment: @IONELABUCIU Can you add more of your work/attempts /context to the problem? EG expand out the LHS

Comment: @CalvinLin Ok. i will

Comment: @CalvinLin I edited it.

Comment: If $a=\min\{x,2\}$, $b=\min\{y,2\}$, $c=\min\{z,2\}$, then it is possible to prove that the product is less than or equal to $2^{ax+by+cz+3}$ which is always less than or equal to $2^{x^2+y^2+z^2+3}\,.\;$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Calvin Lin's idea might be worth an answer here.

First replace with $2^{x-1} + 1\le 2^x$, then the product becomes 8 terms. Without loss of generality, let $x\ge y\ge z \ge 1$.

The largest term is $2^{2x + y}$, if $x=1$, then $x=y=z=1$, the inequality is true. So just focus on $x\ge 2$ (since all are integers), then

$$2^{2x + y} \le 2^{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$$

which means the product is $\le  8 \cdot 2^{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$.

Comment: I think it is possible to prove a better inequality, in fact the product is less than or equal to $\,2^{2x+2y+2z+3}\,.\;$

Comment: that is better when all x y z no less than 2. @Angelo

Comment: @Yimin Thank you so much for your answer! Now I understand it. i have just a little question; how can we demonstrate that $2^{x-1} + 1\le 2^x$?

Comment: @IONELABUCIU, you can cancel $2^{x-1}$ on both sides, then only to show $1\le 2^{x-1}$.

Comment: @Yimin, if $a=\min\{x,2\}$, $b=\min\{y,2\}$, $c=\min\{z,2\}$, then it is possible to prove that the product is less than or equal to $2^{ax+by+cz+3}$ which is always less than or equal to $2^{x^2+y^2+z^2+3}\,.\;$